# iOS Swift Parse Local Data Store unpin doesn't work when offline

Tags: ios, local-storage, offline, delete-file, parse-server

This is not a pointer object issue the unpin seems to only fail when device is offline (not connected to internet)

Query:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Test")
query.fromLocalDatastore()
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
   if let objects = objects {
      print(objects)
   }
}
```

Save:

```
let newTest = PFObject(className: "Test")
newTest["info"] = "Test"
newTest.pinInBackground()
newTest.saveEventually()
```

I tried saving while online and offline - I thought maybe I couldn't unpin it until it reaches the server however it doesn't unpin from local either way

Unpin / delete:

```
newTest.unpinInBackground()
newTest.deleteEventually()
```

I tried removing the delete eventually thinking maybe it had to stay pinned until it was successfully deleted from server however this too didn't change the results

When I call unpinInBackground in a block with a completion it returns as successfully unpinned however when I perform the local query the object still returns

I tried using the .unpin() with a try/catch - same results

When internet is restored and app is restarted all changes sync and both the local datastore and cloud database have the correct data

Is this the expected behavior? Is it not possible to unpin from local when offline?

When I run this code with the device connected to internet the whole time it works perfectly as expected

I am testing on the Simulator iOS 14.1 - xCode 112.1 - and have not yet tested on a physical device

I'm on Parse iOS SDK 19.0.0 - Parse Server 3.7.2

Comment: Even if you unpin, I believe that the object will continue showing up (unless you restart the app). But, after deleteEventually, the object should not show up anymore, as stated in here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#using-the-local-datastore

Comment: Thank you yes this is correct. After more testing I have determined that saveEventually() and deleteEventually() will keep the object pinned locally until it successfully saves or deletes from the cloud. In my case restarting the app isn't an option and the local data is the most important to be correct at all times so I have decided to NOT use saveEventually or deleteEventually - instead I will only use pinInBackground and unpinInBackground then perform my own cloud syncs at appropriate times with saveInBackground only when internet is available